# undefined factory elasticsearch6

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

after enable Elasticsearch6+ in backend, i receive the error 
undefined factory elasticsearch6 
at catalog and search page. I have done a reindex, but it doesn't change.

Magento 2.3.2

System.log:

```
[2019-09-13 10:07:26] main.ERROR: Undefined factory elasticsearch6 [] []
```

elasticsearch.log:

`[2019-09-13T11:53:37,811][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.5gb[6.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:53:37,812][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-09-13T11:54:07,030][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:54:07,743][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v1/WIZTKDgRQKS9jqU3LQmhNw] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:54:07,829][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.5gb[6.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:54:26,422][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:54:26,767][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v1/oO3FnqXxR8mC-mVSR7a40Q] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:54:37,849][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.5gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:54:37,849][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-09-13T11:55:07,879][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.4gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:55:13,070][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:55:13,439][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v2/a61bJnaZS9iPo9CJAq0gQQ] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:55:28,891][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:55:29,224][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v2/AWsDG1l4Rpm9HLb4JdLxXg] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:55:37,914][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.4gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:55:37,914][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-09-13T11:56:04,621][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v1/oO3FnqXxR8mC-mVSR7a40Q] deleting index
[2019-09-13T11:56:04,800][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:56:05,127][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v1/l6itWpybTM6su6Xr-AUJqw] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:56:07,961][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.4gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:56:17,909][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v1/WIZTKDgRQKS9jqU3LQmhNw] deleting index
[2019-09-13T11:56:18,110][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:56:18,422][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v2/xVEavASvRaGDKtHX0kbbNQ] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:56:37,990][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.4gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:56:37,990][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-09-13T11:57:08,026][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.3gb[5.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:57:08,626][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v1/l6itWpybTM6su6Xr-AUJqw] deleting index
[2019-09-13T11:57:08,822][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_4_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:57:09,141][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_4_v1/qob41HB_QZyaXxEPkQ0ajg] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:57:38,050][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.3gb[6%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:57:38,050][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2019-09-13T11:58:08,066][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [7axjJVpqRPi4DyFDmqw16g][7axjJVp][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 9.3gb[5.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2019-09-13T11:58:08,820][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:58:09,151][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v1/fJIqaKRDR2qbBqjfxUPiBA] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:58:10,686][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:58:10,990][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v1/oizaJWf0T7mJu5TKBQl6qg] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:58:12,362][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v1/oizaJWf0T7mJu5TKBQl6qg] update_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,840][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low] from [85%] to [2gb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,840][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high] from [90%] to [1gb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,840][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage] from [95%] to [500mb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,841][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.info.update.interval] from [30s] to [1m]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,841][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low] from [85%] to [2gb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,841][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high] from [90%] to [1gb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:27,841][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterSettings  ] [7axjJVp] updating [cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage] from [95%] to [500mb]
[2019-09-13T11:58:38,101][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [7axjJVp] rerouting shards: [one or more nodes has gone under the high or low watermark]
[2019-09-13T11:59:09,071][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_1_v2/AWsDG1l4Rpm9HLb4JdLxXg] deleting index
[2019-09-13T11:59:09,242][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v3] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:59:09,540][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v3/eyERgd7sRoKnmEqYCBVscA] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T11:59:14,991][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope2_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T11:59:15,284][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope2_v1/9rsPHX0HR8GxEHPKQSKP7g] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:00:04,471][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_2_v2/a61bJnaZS9iPo9CJAq0gQQ] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:00:04,622][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:00:04,929][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_3_v1/JUVDuxuCTvCWtPI8aNUGaQ] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:00:37,158][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope1_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:00:37,453][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope1_v1/fBqaoRCxRr6KSrmuQ4rUiA] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:01:01,783][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_4_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:01:02,082][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_4_v2/gxhoifvHSuq6NnDkt2FULw] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:02:01,753][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope3_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:02:02,041][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope3_v1/g0xugvTnQEqjpxFee3WFxQ] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:02:08,111][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_4_v1/qob41HB_QZyaXxEPkQ0ajg] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:02:08,267][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:02:08,573][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v2/lfS1ts8hQ6mnYRF5sfm_Og] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:02:10,095][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v2/lfS1ts8hQ6mnYRF5sfm_Og] update_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:03:14,183][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_product_8_v1/oizaJWf0T7mJu5TKBQl6qg] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:03:14,327][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope1_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:03:14,574][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope1_v2/ooa9mgB4SgO7VbXDvIdVeA] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:03:29,086][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope4_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:03:29,353][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope4_v1/O5WvkOliStiNHEcStPcTvg] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:04:17,022][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope8_v1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:04:17,263][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope8_v1/NswXkK6oQbqyelqQCMPz8A] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:04:27,300][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope1_v1/fBqaoRCxRr6KSrmuQ4rUiA] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:04:27,362][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope2_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:04:27,592][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope2_v2/CmTeTsQxRKKioOlqcw5l8g] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:05:40,428][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope2_v1/9rsPHX0HR8GxEHPKQSKP7g] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:05:40,482][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope3_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:05:40,720][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope3_v2/yryVcA6MRwe2TEU89qWLmQ] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:06:52,116][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope3_v1/g0xugvTnQEqjpxFee3WFxQ] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:06:52,167][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope4_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:06:52,409][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope4_v2/Y-EHap26RT-1yW31hHz4ig] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:06:54,967][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope4_v1/O5WvkOliStiNHEcStPcTvg] deleting index
[2019-09-13T12:06:55,025][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope8_v2] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2019-09-13T12:06:55,281][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope8_v2/YBEeabgLRR28gBQw5L9z1w] create_mapping [document]
[2019-09-13T12:06:58,154][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataDeleteIndexService] [7axjJVp] [magento2_mst_search_magento_catalog_category_2_scope8_v1/NswXkK6oQbqyelqQCMPz8A] deleting index`

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try following commands

```
//Optional
composer update magento/module-elasticsearch

//Optional
composer update magento/module-elasticsearch-6

php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```